# Inline css is being erased in text editor when I save. It creates an ugly html button that leads nowhere

Tags: html, css, button, sliding

I'm trying to add a button to my html text editor on a category page in **`Lightspeed Retail`**. I can make the code work in **`js fiddle`** just fine, but when I put the code into the text editor, it doesn't work. When I save it, it ereases everything and gives me a html button that leads nowhere. I'm incredibly new to trying to figure this stuff out, so it's a bit daunting.

I tried to create a seperate `css` to reference, but it is above my understanding. I am trying to stick with inline since it seems to work in jsfiddle. If I must do **`external style sheet`** I may require some extra guidance.

(I had to erase     from the code to get it to appear properly on here)

```
  .button {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #c7057d;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
  }

  .button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }

  .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }

</style>
```

Pink button that when moused over has a sliding effect, that leads to booking page for company.

Comment: You've absolutely buried a critical detail: What is `Lightspeed Retail`? I'm assuming they offer some sort of code editor that you are using, and that is where this phenomenon is occuring?

Comment: Yes, they seperate each page into categories. From there, each page has a text editor that you can change the styling of each page in using html. When I put the css into this page, it will disappear once saved. I'm sorry if I am not clear enough.

Comment: if you provide `js fiddle` link where the `css` code is working then it will be more easy to answer

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil here is a link https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3cwcvemR3i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate `css` file as follows;

```css
      .button {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #c7057d;
        border: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 5px;
      }

      .button span {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .button span:after {
        content: '\00bb';
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: -20px;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .button:hover span {
        padding-right: 25px;
      }

      .button:hover span:after {
        opacity: 1;
        right: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fittingbutton.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://allegrodanceboutique.simplybook.me/v2/"><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Book Now </span></button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** you should past the `css` code in `fittingbutton.css` file and paste the html code in the separate `.html` file.

---

**Update:** In case the `<span>` is being erased, you can use `<div>` instead as follows;

```css
      .button {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #c7057d;
        border: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 5px;
      }

      .button div {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .button div:after {
        content: '\00bb';
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: -20px;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .button:hover div {
        padding-right: 25px;
      }

      .button:hover div:after {
        opacity: 1;
        right: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fittingbutton.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://allegrodanceboutique.simplybook.me/v2/"><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><div>Book Now </div></button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is perfect, except when I put it into the source code, it erases everything and leaves "<button class="button" style="vertical-align: middle;">Book Now </button>" as the only code in place of it.

Comment: does it erases `span` also?

Comment: @WillM you can also replace the `<span>` with `<div>`